# What is the reason for low GPU util when training machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, cpu

Suppose I have 8 gpus on a server. (From 0 to 7)

When I train a simple (and small) model on a gpu #0, it takes about 20 minutes per epoch.
However, when I load more than 5 or 6 models on some gpus,
for example, 2 experiments per gpu from gpu #0 to #2, (6 in total)
the training time per epoch explodes. ( about 1 hour ),

When I train 2 models per gpu for all gpus ( 16 experiments in total ), it takes about 3 hours to complete an epoch.

When I see the CPU utilization, it is fine.
But GPU utilization drops.

What is the reason for the drop, and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways of using multi-GPUs for deep learning:

- Use `torch.nn.DataParallel(module)` (DP)

This function is quite discouraged by the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) because it replicates the entire module in all GPUs at **each forward pass**. At the end of forward pass, the models are destroyed. Therefore, when you have big models it could be an important bottleneck in your training time and even slow it by compared to single GPU. It could be the case for instance when you freeze a large part of big module for fine tuning.
That's why you may consider using:

- `torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(module, device_ids=)` (DDP) [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html#torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel)

This function often requires refactoring your code a little bit more but it improves the efficiency because it copy the models on GPUs **only once**, at the beginning of the training. The models are persistent over time and the gradients are synchronized after each backward pass via hooks. To go further, you can distributed data and optimizer as well to avoid data transfer. You can do it simply (as well as parallelized modules) using [torch-ignite/distributed](https://pytorch.org/ignite/distributed.html).

I don't know what kind of method you tried but I encourage you to use DDP instead of DP if you are using it.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much for your reply.
Actually, I am using DP, but I don't share the model on multi gpus.
It means that one experiment works only on one gpu though I use DP. 
And also, model is not really big. It only has about 4 million parameters. 

Is it also helpful to use DDP in this case?

I cannot figure out for low-gpu util & speed drop, when I load several tiny experiments.

Comment: In theory DP can be used without drawback if you have only one GPU but in this case I don't understand why do you need parallelism?

Comment: Ah, actually I don't have to use DP as you said if I use a single GPU environment. I am just using the boiler-plate code that I made previously :) Thank you for your reply !

Answer (score 1):

Due to their extreme parallelism, GPUs process data considerably quicker than CPUs, yet they are less flexible than CPUs. A GPU cannot manage all of a computer's inputs and outputs as a CPU can, which has a huge and diverse set of instructions. Individual CPU cores are faster (measured by CPU clock speed) and smarter (measured by available instruction sets) than individual GPU cores; however, the sheer quantity of GPU cores and the enormous amount of parallelism they offer more than make up for the disparity in single-core clock speed and restricted instruction sets.

The most efficient use of GPUs is for repeated, highly parallel processing jobs.

Use your CPU if your code is not repetitive or extremely parallel.